# BotState object keeps value from other conversations

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I am trying to save a object in BotState as below

```
protected readonly BotState ConversationState;
protected readonly BotState UserState;

public DialogBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState)
{
    ConversationState = conversationState;
    UserState = userState;
}

public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);           
    await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
}

protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");

    var userStateAccessor = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
    var userProfile= await userStateAccessor .GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile(), cancellationToken);
   if(string.IsNullOrEmp(userProfile.UserId))
   {
       userProfile.ConversationId  = turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id;
       userProfile.UserId = turnContext. turnContext.Activity.From.Id;
   }
    await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
}
```

the If condition in above code is always 'false' after first access since deployment. i.e BotState object UserProfile keeps value from previous conversation.
Please help me, if there is anything wrong here

Answer (score 2):

This is as designed. UserState will keep data for the user across all conversations. ConversationState, on the other hand, keeps the data only for the current conversation. [Here is some more information about managing states in Bot Framework.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

So here, your code is saying "if user ID is null, save the current conversation ID and user ID". Once you've set that, you should never end up in that block unless you delete the user state object. I don't see downstream where you are using these values, but it stands to reason that if you are not hitting that if block, then you already have those values saved and don't *need* to hit the if block.

I'm not sure what you are using the values for, but I would be careful about saving conversation ID in user state. Especially the way this code is set up, the conversation ID will NOT update when you are in a new conversation, so you will end up with an outdated value. You could save it in an "else" statement, but then I would question why you need an if block at all (i.e. just reset the conversation and user IDs every turn).